# Spacing groups instanced from collections based on their size

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections

#### Random Car generator

I've made a random car generator that works by picking parts from 3 collections, **front**, **middle** and **back**, then randomly scale the middle section's length and randomly picks a material, to give some variations.
Here's what some of the results looks like when changing the seed of the random value:
[image: 20 random cars]

So far so good. Then I want to take it further and make a:

#### Random Traffic Jam generator

The idea being to have many different cars following each other, with a group input to control the space between them. The problem I'm faced with is that I can't get the spacing to take into account the size of each car.

Here's the different approaches I took, using a simplified version of the first car generator:

##### Attempt 1

[image: traffic jam 1]

The space remains the same, but only the first car is random and the others are copies of it. I think it only works because the cars are all the same and the bounding boxes would just combine themselves if they were different.

[image: traffic jam 1 nodes]

##### Attempt 2

[image: traffic jam 2]

The cars are random but the space between them is constant and doesn't take into account the size of the car, which makes long cars crash into each other and small ones be surrounded by big gaps.

[image: traffic jam 2 nodes]

---

For the last 2 days I've been trying a lot of different things, using modulo and compare, dividing and flooring to address each car, realizing instances then measuring their bounding boxes, accumulating fields, and even capturing attributes, but I'm getting nowhere and my brain is turning to soup.

I know I could just create a few variations, put them in a collection and use that to make the traffic jam (and will end up doing that if nothing else works), but I would prefer not to as the final result will have 100s of cars and I like the idea of all of them being random, not repeats of a few cars.

As a bonus, it would be great to still be able to apply a random material to each separate car.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: spacing cars 1]

Geometry Nodes:

[image: spacing cars Geometry Nodes 1]

The node cirled with red is the sum of the Y dimensions of the front and back parts, the resulting value is added to the scale of the middle part multiplied by it's Y dimension.

**Important:**

This assumes that all parts in a collection share the same dimensions, which is true in the simplified file you provided, but doesn't seems to be in the first image of your question. I didn't found a node to get bounding boxes of multiple instances as a field, so for that I currently have no solution (**Edit: there's now a method for that below in 'Variable Dimension Istances'**).

### $$\text{Material per Car}$$

[image: a material per car]

First we create some materials in the object which hold the Geometry Nodes, the link type of all materials needs to be **Object**:

[image: Materials]

Then, in the Geometry Nodes, we generate an integer anonymous attribute for each point in the line, the value generated is limited to the material index range (I used 5 materials):

[image: capture random integer per point]

The resulting attribute is then used to set the material index after realizing all instances:

[image: set material index of realized instances]

### $$\text{Color per Car}$$

If you want, instead of selecting a random existing material by generating a random material index, you can generate a random color per point in the line and pass it to a single material as an attribute:

[image: random color per point Geo Nodes]

[image: Attribute properties]

[image: naming attribute]

[image: Single material]

### $$\text{Variable Dimension Instances}$$

[image: parts with variable dimensions stacked with spacing]

With Python we can create an object and store in it's vertices the Y dimension of all objects in the collections, then in Geometry Nodes we transfer the values using the same index that we use to pick an instance.

This method supports front, middle and back parts of varying dimensions.

```
import bpy

objName = "InstList_Dims"

frt = bpy.data.collections["frt"]
mid = bpy.data.collections["mid"]
bck = bpy.data.collections["bck"]

counts = [len(frt.objects), len(mid.objects), len(bck.objects)]
max = max(counts) #size of biggest collection

parts = bpy.data.collections["parts"]
dimensions = bpy.data.objects.get(objName)

if dimensions:
    dimensions.data.clear_geometry()
    
    if not parts.objects.get(objName):
        parts.objects.link(dimensions)
else:
    dimensions = bpy.data.objects.new(objName, bpy.data.meshes.new("dims_mesh"))
    parts.objects.link(dimensions)

verts = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0] for y in range(max)]

for i, obj in enumerate(frt.objects):
    verts[i][0] = obj.dimensions[1]
    
for i, obj in enumerate(mid.objects):
    verts[i][1] = obj.dimensions[1]
    
for i, obj in enumerate(bck.objects):
    verts[i][2] = obj.dimensions[1]
    
dimensions.data.from_pydata(verts, [], [])
dimensions.location = counts
```

What this does is first check if the object '*InstList_Dims*' exists. If it does, it's geometry is deleted. If not, the object is created. After that a vertex array is created with the size of the biggest parts collection, this is where, for every part, it's Y dimension is stored in the same index as the part's index in it's collection:

- Y dimension from front parts are stored in the $X$ coordinate of vertices.
- Y dimension from middle parts are stored in the $Y$ coordinate of vertices.
- Y dimension from back parts are stored in the $Z$ coordinate of vertices.

After this, the data is send to the object's mesh. The part count is stored in the object's position:

- Front part count is stored in the object's $X$ coordinate.
- Middle part count is stored in the object's $Y$ coordinate.
- Back part count is stored in the object's $Z$ coordinate.

If you modify or add parts after running the script, you just need to run it again:

[image: script rerun]

Now we go to Geometry Nodes:

[image: Geometry Nodes]

[image: Random Index Node Group]

[image: Instance Parts 2 Node Group]

Here we instance the parts and transfer the dimensions from the generated object using the same random index, which is limited to the part count (from the object position) minus one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, even if it doesn't solve everything it's a great start! I think I understand the logic of it apart from the "field at index 0" node. What does that do? Otherwise, for the front and back parts, there's 3 different sizes and maybe I can order them in three groups within the collection (by renaming them), modulo the random seed then adapt the Value depending of which group came up. Also any idea on how I would change the material of each car? (sorry, a lot of extra questions here :D)

Comment: Okay, cool, worked out that the field at index 0 was just to keep the first car centred, nice! Also, I just made all my fronts and backs be the same length so problem solved. Still need to work on the material bit :)

Comment: @wilks I added to the answer a way to set a random material per car.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for sticking with it even tho it was more than one question really. Only note is that for the 2nd method I had to change the Attribute Domain to Point in the Group Output

Comment: @wilks I added to the answer a way to work with instances with variable dimensions in case you're still working on this project and wants to use variable dimensions. I had this idea in mind, but i had to learn some more bpy.